# Tensorflow retrained graph in C# (Tensorflowsharp)

Tags: tensorflow

I'am just trying to use a retrained inception model in Tensorflow sharp in Unity.
The retrained model was prepared with optimize_for_inference and is working like a charm in python.
But it is pretty inaccurate in c#.

the code works like this:
First i get the Picture

```
//webcamtexture transformed to picture in jpg
var pic = _texture.EncodeToJpg();
//added Picture to queue for the object detection thread
_detectedObjects.addTens(pic);
```

After that a thread will handle each collected picture

```
public void HandlePicture(byte[] picture)
{
    var tensor = ImageUtil.CreateTensorFromImageFile(picture);
        var runner = session.GetRunner();

        runner.AddInput(g_input, tensor).Fetch(g_output);
        var output = runner.Run();

        var bestIdx = 0;
        float best = 0;
        var result = output[0];
        var rshape = result.Shape;
        var probabilities = ((float[][])result.GetValue(jagged: true))[0];
        for (int r = 0; r < probabilities.Length; r++)
        {
            if (probabilities[r] > best)
            {
                bestIdx = r;
                best = probabilities[r];
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Tensorflow thinks this is: " + labels[bestIdx] + " Prob : " + best * 100);
}
```

so my guess is:

1.it has something to do with retrained graphs (because i can't find any application/test it is used and working).

2.It has something to do with how i handle the picture transform into a tensor?! (but if that is wrong i could need help there, the code further down)

to transform the picture i'am also using a graph like it is used in the tensorsharp example

```
public static class ImageUtil
{
    // Convert the image in filename to a Tensor suitable as input to the Inception model.
    public static TFTensor CreateTensorFromImageFile(byte[] contents, TFDataType destinationDataType = TFDataType.Float)
    {
        // DecodeJpeg uses a scalar String-valued tensor as input.
        var tensor = TFTensor.CreateString(contents);

        TFGraph graph;
        TFOutput input, output;

        // Construct a graph to normalize the image
        ConstructGraphToNormalizeImage(out graph, out input, out output, destinationDataType);

        // Execute that graph to normalize this one image
        using (var session = new TFSession(graph))
        {
            var normalized = session.Run(
                     inputs: new[] { input },
                     inputValues: new[] { tensor },
                     outputs: new[] { output });

            return normalized[0];
        }
    }

    // The inception model takes as input the image described by a Tensor in a very
    // specific normalized format (a particular image size, shape of the input tensor,
    // normalized pixel values etc.).
    //
    // This function constructs a graph of TensorFlow operations which takes as
    // input a JPEG-encoded string and returns a tensor suitable as input to the
    // inception model.
    private static void ConstructGraphToNormalizeImage(out TFGraph graph, out TFOutput input, out TFOutput output, TFDataType destinationDataType = TFDataType.Float)
    {
        // Some constants specific to the pre-trained model at:
        // https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip
        //
        // - The model was trained after with images scaled to 224x224 pixels.
        // - The colors, represented as R, G, B in 1-byte each were converted to
        //   float using (value - Mean)/Scale.

        const int W = 299;
        const int H = 299;
        const float Mean = 128;
        const float Scale = 1;
        graph = new TFGraph();


        input = graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.String);

        output = graph.Cast(graph.Div(
            x: graph.Sub(
                x: graph.ResizeBilinear(
                    images: graph.ExpandDims(
                        input: graph.Cast(
                            graph.DecodeJpeg(contents: input, channels: 3), DstT: TFDataType.Float),
                        dim: graph.Const(0, "make_batch")),
                    size: graph.Const(new int[] { W, H }, "size")),
                y: graph.Const(Mean, "mean")),
            y: graph.Const(Scale, "scale")), destinationDataType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Why are you using EncodeToPNG() though? you 
further use DecodeJPEG to decode the image. Shouldn't EncodeToJPEG be used in the first line of your code?

Comment: That is true. I tested it with both and at the time i posted this i edited it back but probably not on both ends. So while testing i used Decode /Encode PNG/JPG of the same type ;-) . I Will edit it.

Comment: You will have Problems as soon as you try to build it on Mobile. See my other thread about that. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117704/how-to-transform-bytedecoded-as-png-or-jpg-to-tensorflows-tensor) . Decode/Encode JPG/PNG do not work on mobiles.

Comment: Of course that does not fix the accuracy problems.

Comment: yeah I also found that it had to do with resolution of images I feed the tensor with. The lower the resolution the higher were the certainties. Eventually I gave up on tensorflowsharp and am now building a python server that will process the images for my mobile clients (hololens, etc)